# How to deploy the kinesis-video-producer Docker image from AWS's own ECR to Fargate using CDK in TypeScript?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-amplify, aws-cdk, amazon-ecr, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm trying to stand up a proof of concept that ingests an RTSP video stream into Kinesis Video. The [provided documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/examples-gstreamer-plugin.html) has a docker image all set up that seems to have everything I need to do this, hosted by AWS on `546150905175.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`. What I am having trouble with, though, is getting that deployment (via an Amplify Custom category, in TypeScript CDK) to work.

I've tried different variations on

```
import * as iam from "@aws-cdk/aws-iam";
import * as ecs from "@aws-cdk/aws-ecs";
import * as ec2 from "@aws-cdk/aws-ec2";

const kinesisUserAccessKey = new iam.AccessKey(this, 'KinesisStreamUserAccessKey', {
    user: kinesisStreamUser,
})

const servicePrincipal = new iam.ServicePrincipal('ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com');
const executionRole = new iam.Role(this, 'IngestVideoTaskDefExecutionRole', {
    assumedBy: servicePrincipal,
    managedPolicies: [
        iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'),
    ]
});

const taskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, 'IngestVideoTaskDef', {
    cpu: 512,
    memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
    executionRole,
})

const image = ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('546150905175.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/kinesis-video-producer-sdk-cpp-amazon-linux:latest');

taskDefinition.addContainer('IngestVideoContainer', {
    command: [
        'gst-launch-1.0',
        'rtspsrc',
        `location="${locationParam.secretValue.toString()}"`,
        'short-header=TRUE',
        '!',
        'rtph264depay',
        '!',
        'video/x-h264,',
        'format=avc,alignment=au',
        '!',
        'kvssink',
        `stream-name="${cfnStream.name}"`,
        'storage-size=512',
        `access-key="${kinesisUserAccessKey.accessKeyId}"`,
        `secret-key="${kinesisUserAccessKey.secretAccessKey.toString()}"`,
        `aws-region="${REGION}"`,
        // `aws-region="${cdk.Aws.REGION}"`,
    ],
    image,
    logging: new ecs.AwsLogDriver({
        streamPrefix: 'IngestVideoContainer',
    }),
})

const service = new ecs.FargateService(this, 'IngestVideoService', {
    cluster,
    taskDefinition,
    desiredCount: 1,
    securityGroups: [
        ec2.SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(this, 'DefaultSecurityGroup', SECURITY_GROUP_ID)
    ],
    vpcSubnets: {
        subnets: SUBNET_IDS.map(subnetId => ec2.Subnet.fromSubnetId(this, subnetId, subnetId)),
    }
})
```

But it seems like regardless of what I do, an `amplify push` just stays in 'in progress' for like an hour until I go into the CloudFormation console and cancel the stack update, but deep in the my way to the ECS Console I managed to find an actual error message:

> Resourceinitializationerror: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post "https://api.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/": dial tcp 52.94.177.118:443: i/o timeout

It seems to be some kind of networking issue, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any assistance you can provide would be wonderful. Cheers!

Comment: The subnet in which you are deploying does it have NAT connected or is an isolated subnet. If it is isolated subnet with no outbound internet route you might need to create ECR vpc endpoints

Comment: @VikramS It has a a public subnet but I found out from another answer that Fargate needs assignPublicIp: true to access ECR. Thanks for responding, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For those stuck with similar issues, you have to give it an execution role with AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy, which I already edited above, and set assignPublicIp: true in the service.